# AFNetworking POST parameter with underscore

Tags: json, post, afnetworking

This data posts perfectly fine to my web service in "Postman" but not in AFNetworking, so I know it's an issue with AFNetworking or AFNetworking's handling of NSDictionary.

I am using the following simple code to post:

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *newSession = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
        newSession.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
        newSession.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
NSDictionary *tryParameters = @{@"tripID": @"1234", @"tailNum": @"N15HEHE", @"legNum": @"1", @"file_date": @"2016"};
[newSession POST:HTTP_POST_TRIP_DATA parameters:tryParameters progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {
            NSLog(@"TRY");
        } success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {

            NSString *status = [responseObject valueForKey:@"status"];

            NSLog(@"RESPONSE: %@", responseObject);

            if ([status isEqualToString:@"success"]) {

                files(YES);
            } else {

                files(NO);
            }

        } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
            //NOT success
            files(NO);   
        }];
```

On the LAST "tryParameters" I have a key/value of "file_date" : @"2016".  That underscore seems to be the issue. If I remove the "_" (underscore) from the file_date key, everything seems to process. (Of course I get an error from my server saying that "file_date" was never given.).  But if I leave the "_" in my "file_date" key, the POST request fails and I get...

```
[0] (null)  @"com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response" : (no summary)   
[1] (null)  @"NSErrorFailingURLKey" : @"http://xxxxxxx.com/xxx/createTrip"  
[2] (null)  @"com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data" : (no summary)   
[3] (null)  @"NSLocalizedDescription" : @"Request failed: unauthorized (401)"
```

I can not figure out why the "_" is such an issue. I can read it in FROM my server in GET requests but when I try to POST, it fails.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for anyone with this same issue. I figured out the problem.
Basically, the default requestSerializer for AFNetworking does not allow for special characters. You must change this line of code...

```
newSession.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
```

to this line of code...

```
newSession.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializerWithWritingOptions:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted];
```

The "pretty" option allows for special characters and allowed for my previous code to work just fine.

It took a while to sort this out so hopefully this helps someone.